# Mysql query for displaying row value as column header dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

my table looks ike this

```
dt        ticker         open
1            A                1.2
1            B                 6
2            A                 1.4
2            B                 6.5
```

I would like it to turn out to be

```
dt           A            B
1            1.2         1.4
2            6            6.5
```

I tried using `mysql` query in below format

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'MAX(IF(ticker= ''',
ticker,
''', open, NULL)) AS ',
ticker
)
) INTO @sql
FROM properties;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT dt, ', @sql, ' FROM properties GROUP BY dt');
```

while executing the query in `phpmyadmin` I am getting below `error` .

```
Warning in .\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#436
mysqli_fetch_fields() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: below are additional error messages . the query is executing ,but looking into rows i am getting errors   Backtrace

.\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php#436: mysqli_fetch_fields(boolean true)
.\libraries\DatabaseInterface.php#2641: PMA\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli->getFieldsMeta(boolean true)
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1848: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->getFieldsMeta(boolean true)
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2199: PMA_getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(
boolean true,
array,
string 'qc',
string 'tbl_main',
NULL,
NULL,

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code. And the comments section is not the place to put edits to your question

Comment: Google "pivot query MySQL"

Comment: No. Do the pivoting in php